# Can't dockerize Nuxt.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nuxt.js

I have simple Nuxt.js application and I want to dockerize it. Here is the script:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8010

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I build it and run container it seems to work and I can see something like this:

```
Entrypoint app = server.js server.js.map

READY  Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8010
```

But when I'm trying to see it in browser I get just error - `This page isn’t working`.

So, in general, how can I dockerize my `Nuxt.js` application and make it work on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app binds to 127.0.0.1 which means that it'll only accept connections from inside the container. By reading the docs, it seems you can set the HOST environment variable to the binding address you want. Try this, which sets it to 0.0.0.0 which means that the app accepts connections from everywhere

```
FROM node
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8010
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When running it, you should see `READY  Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8010` rather than `READY  Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8010`